# HtmlAgilityPack get tables based on cell value

Tags: powershell, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have 1000+ HTML documents which contain various tables each and are using PowerShell to process them.

I am looking to extract specific tables, these can be identified by first row, which is used for headings and one of the cells always has the word "measurement".

Since the HTML is .doc export the word can be nested in a `<span>` or `<p>` so ideally I would be able to ignore that level of nesting.

I've tried something like:

```
$tables = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[* = 'measurement']")
```

but get nothing back.

Here's some more HTML, unfortunately I cannot post all of it, but it's the MS Word export as HTML document:

```
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
   style='border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-layout-alt:fixed;border:none;
   mso-border-alt:double windowtext 1.5pt;mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
<tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
   <td width=192 valign=top style='width:2.0in;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
      padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoHeading9><span lang=EN-CA>Areas</span></p>
   </td>
   <td width=288 valign=top style='width:3.0in;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
      border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoHeading9><span lang=EN-CA>measurements</span></p>
   </td>
   <td width=346 valign=top style='width:3.6in;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
      border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoHeading9><span lang=EN-CA>Objectives</span></p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Post minimal sample HTML that would demonstrate how your code failing

Comment: FYI, to format your code: block/select the code, then click on `{}` button at the top of the editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further information or sample HTML markup I can only suggest to use descendant axis `//` to get all descendant nodes no matter how deep they are nested within `<table>` node :

```
//table[.//* = 'measurement']
```

**UPDATE :**

After looking at the sample HTML, I think there might be a more efficient way by using a more specific xpath, for example:

```
//table[tr/td//* = 'measurement']
```

but specific xpath also bring more risk of leaving some tables that supposed to be selected. The decision is yours, according to the entire document structure and how much efficiency is needed.

Comment: I think you got it, let me test, but getting results back and the number looks correct.

Comment: @Radek you are welcome :) consider the **UPDATE** section too, may or may not suites your needs though